# Maven with TestNG and Selenium, TestNG file being ignored

Tags: eclipse, maven, webdriver, testng, pom.xml

**Story:** So I am running a WebDriver2 test suite with TestNG and all that's bundled up in a Maven architecture.  I built everything in Eclipse project first, then converted this over to a Maven project.  I am not a programmer but I can hack my way through Java, I am new to Maven but pretty good with TestNG and Selenium and from everything I have researched I am approaching this correctly, I have to be missing something stupid.

**Problem:** I am running this all in Eclipse with Maven plugin, when I run POM as TEST I get an error:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: Parameter 'dataMode' is required by @Configuration of method prepareDriver but has not been marked @Optional or defined
```

So POM setup thusly for SureFire to grab my file, testNG dependency also set and appears to work since my error is coming from TestNG itself:

```
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>src\test\resources\testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

I have also passed in the parameters to this plugin as well:

```
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <dataMode>Custom</dataMode>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <log_level>DEBUG</log_level>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
```

Everything in my TestNG file is correct, if I run as a TestNG test just from the testng.xml everything runs like it is supposed to, if you want that code I will update but that part works, parameters are in there correctly.

Also, when I execute the POM as TEST I get a report that 2 out of 11 tests failed...  I don't have 11 tests, if you go by my testNG.xml I have only 2 @Test's that it would find, I think it's counting every TestNG annotation in this portion of my test-suite...

My theory is that it's trying to run without the TestNG file and just running every TestNG annotation in any file it finds but I don't have it setup to do that, or do I?

Comment: Well, do you get the first error or does it run.  Are these separate issues or come in the same output?

Comment: I get the posted error message no matter what I do...  the first bit of code is my current incarnation, it resides in the <build></build> section of the POM, I have also fooled with that changing it to <test></test> to no avail.

It tries to run.  This error occurs no matter what, all of my testcases require these parameters...  I have nothing but tests, nothing in the main section codewise, just a test suite organized in the src/test/java

Comment: The message that 2/11 tests failed is in the same error report saying that I am missing parameters, there is a ATBeforeSuite and a ATBeforeMethod that I think it is referring to, the latter has the ATParameter tag

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                 <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```